# adding custom css to theme

Tags: magento2

probably missing something simple here, but I can not get my css to load after adding it to new child theme

Here is my folder structure

[image]

I have added the following into my /layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <css src="css/custom.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
</head>
```

And the header in my sit has changed and is referencing the files in the  tag as expected

```
<title>Home page</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://dev.modzinc.co.uk/pub/static/version1487891140/frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/mage/calendar.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://dev.modzinc.co.uk/pub/static/version1487891140/frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="http://dev.modzinc.co.uk/pub/static/version1487891140/frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/css/styles-l.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="http://dev.modzinc.co.uk/pub/static/version1487891140/frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/css/custom.css" />
```

put when I open the url : http://dev.modzinc.co.uk/pub/static/version1487891140/frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/css/custom.css

I get this error

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/css/custom.css'
#0    /home/ubodoco/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /home/ubodoco/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#2 /home/ubodoco/public_html/dev/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#3 {main}
```

Through the command line I have tried setup:upgrade    , Cache:clean  , cache:flush and nothing will make it work ??

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong

thanks

Comment: Forgot to say I am on magento CE 2.14 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`? All of your theme assets need to be compiled into the `pub/static/` folders, so check the path is is giving you an error:

```
pub/static/frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/css/custom.css
```

and see if your .css file is in there. If it's not, run the setup command above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the static files are trying to get a specific version in there.

Building on what @circlesix said...

Clear out your `pub/static/frontend` and `var/view_preprocessed` folders, clear your cache and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB` from your root directory again

This should clear the version and your CSS file should start working.

Double check the file exists in

```
 pub/static/frontend/Modzinc/basic/en_GB/css/custom.css
```